# How to return Json data without escape string in RESTful api on Golang

Tags: json, rest, go

I have written an API with Golang. This API does receive data from other services then it responses to users in type of JSON string. Here is the problems I got.

```
type message struct {
    Data string `json:"data"`
}

func test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    data := // Retrieve message that contain backslash
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(message{Data: data})
}
```

`
If there is a backslash in data that receive from other API. This API will send the response with double backslashes.

Example.

Received data:
`"asdasdasd\asdasdasd"`

Response data:
`{"data": "asdasdasd\\asdasdasd"}`

I have try to figure this out. Here what I got. All of this will be fine if I try to print out in the screen by using `fmt.Println()`.

I only get problem when I try to send those out put in JSON string. Therefore, is there any way to send those data without double backslashes?

Comment: Backslash is a special character, it must be escaped, i.e. converted from \ to \\. So the encoder is correct. Why do you want to disable the conversion?

Comment: If your `data` is already a *valid JSON*, then define the `Data` in `message` struct as `json.RawMessage`. Then in the encoder, define the message as `message{Data: json.RawMessage(data)}`

Comment: `{"data": "asdasdasd\\asdasdasd"}` is the correct JSON representation of the string `asdasdasd\asdasdasd`…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a custom method and replace double backslashes with a single one.
Something like that:

```
func JSONMarshal(v interface{}, backslashEscape bool) ([]byte, error) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(v)

    if backslashEscape {
        b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte(`\\`), []byte(`\`), -1)
    }
    return b, err
}
```

The `json/encoder` packages has also `DisableHTMLEscaping`, if set to true, default is false, it allows you to escape HTML chars.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works!!
But there is some issue you need to fix in this code. You have to use backtick **(`)** instead of  double-qoute **(")**

Comment: It seem that your fixed version using single-quote, not backtick or grave accent.

Comment: Edit my answer by clicking edit link. I'm from smartphone and I'll accept your edit

Answer (score 1):

I asked pretty much the same question a couple days ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889437/is-there-a-way-to-format-this-json-in-golang)'s the post.

Basically you don't want your Data to be a `string` but an `interface{}` instead.

```
type message struct {
    Data interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

I think this may apply to you also. And if you want to go RESTFul and return different types of structs, this is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, `json.RawMessage` does the trick.

```golang
data := map[string]interface{}{}
data["date"] = json.RawMessage([]byte(`"\/Date(1590105600000)\/"`))

b := new(bytes.Buffer)
json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(data)

fmt.Println(b.String())
// {"date":"\/Date(1590105600000)\/"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Golang default render will escape JSON, but if you want to disable it you need to define custom renderer like this:

```golang
encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
encoder.SetEscapeHTML(false)
encoder.Encode(data)
```