# Returning a specific category with Wikipedia API (Mediawiki API)

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, wikipedia-api

I am relatively new at Android Studio development, but what I was trying to do was use the Wikipedia API to return a specific category of text on a Wikipedia page onto my app.

For instance, the Wikipedia page for Agile Scrum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)), I would like to return specifically the "product owner" category under 'Roles'.

Things I've tried:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Scrum_(software_development)

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Scrum_(software_development)

Would there be a way to filter out the specific category through Android Studio code?

Ultimate Aim:

The goal is to get a specific category of text, bring it back to the app and then put it into a scroll view. An issue I have seen with just experimenting and putting the wiki intro page info into a scroll view is that there are several json symbols that I would like to remove e.g.

```
</h2>\n<p>
```

Any recommendations as to how to solve my problems would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Reading [Wikipedia's RESTBase](https://en.wiktionary.org/api/rest_v1/#!/Page_content/get_page_segments_title_revision), and from what I understood of your question, you should use the following request URL to get the content:

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/api/rest_v1/page/segments/Scrum_(software_development)%23Product_owner
```

Now for formatting the JSON (to exclude the escapes and whatnot), you should use [interface{}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889524/7520423), like this answer explains more clearly.